# Using JQuery to find and use classes in a table created by php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table with a list of entries from a log. Each entry refers to a specific hard drive. I am trying to make it so that the latest entry shows for each drive and then, when clicked, all previous entries for it will be shown.

My theory so far is to give each entry relating to a specific drive the same class. For example all entries about the drive named "branded1" will have the class "branded1" and then I can use the `:first` selector to show the first entry, and toggle the remaining on click. This works with the following code:

```
$(".branded2:first").click(function(){
            $(".branded2:not(:first)").toggle();
        })
```

The problem is that at the moment I have to have already scripted the classes into my jQuery script in advance but I want the app to be able to update itself. Is there a way that jQuery can search through the table and look for classes? With that info I could then create a similar function for each class automatically. Here is how my table looks:

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Drive Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="Branded2"></a>Branded 2</td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 11:18:13</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded2">
        <td>Branded 2</td>
        <td>Out</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 10:48:37</td>
        <td>shoot</td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="ID1"></a>iD 1</td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 10:47:29</td>
        <td>rushes</td>
        <td>maddie</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a class="Branded7"></a>Branded 7</td>
        <td>Out</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 13:19:11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded7">
        <td>Branded 7</td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 13:19:04</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is sometimes a `<tr>` element given the class name and sometimes an empty `<a>` element?

Comment: I just updated that. I was messing with the variables to change the class and forgot to put the variable for the <a> tag back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [custom `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that HTML5 gives you. jQuery's [`data()` function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) can pull the value and you can use it to build a class name for selecting. Something like this should work:

```js
$("a.hideshow").click(function(e) {
    var classname = $(this).data("toggles");
    $("tr." + classname).not($(this).parents("tr")).toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Drive Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded2">
        <td><a class="hideshow" data-toggles="Branded2">Branded2</a></td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 11:18:13</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded2">
        <td>Branded 2</td>
        <td>Out</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 10:48:37</td>
        <td>shoot</td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ID1">
        <td><a class="hideshow" data-toggles="ID1">ID1</a></td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 10:47:29</td>
        <td>rushes</td>
        <td>maddie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded7">
        <td><a class="hideshow" data-toggles="Branded7">Branded7</a></td>
        <td>Out</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 13:19:11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Branded7">
        <td>Branded 7</td>
        <td>In</td>
        <td>2017-03-26 13:19:04</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>frank</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've also used the jQuery `not()` function to avoid toggling the parent of the clicked element. This lets you apply the class to every associated `<tr>` element, instead of all but the first one.

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked great. I also added another class to additional drive references to make sure they were hidden on load. Thank you!